Bound variables in definite integrals
I have seen many posts that explain this topic, but none that have answered this question: where does the “boundness” from the bound variable in a definite integral come from.
For example, in the following statement:
Let x be a real number. Then: x+1 > x
What I am really saying is
For all x in R —- x+1 > x
There is a quantifier that bounds x, hence the symbol “x” can be replaced for any other symbol.
However, where does this idea arise in a definite integral?

To write a definite integral you do not need an $x$. If $f$ is a nice enough real valued function defined on the interval $[a,b]$ then $\int_a^bf$ is a well defined real number.
Writing that integral with a "variable of integration" as $\int_a^bf(x)dx$ is a very convenient notation we inherited from Liebniz. It properly suggests that the integral is a way to formalize the idea of adding up the areas $f(x)dx$ of infinitely many infinitely thin rectangles for $x$ between $a$ and $b$. That notation  makes it much easier to use the chain rule correctly when "changing variables" in an integral.
Finally, the notation is useful when $f$ is a function of two variables. Then
$$
\int_a^bf(x,t)dt
$$
is a function of the first variable $x$ while
$$
\int_a^bf(x,t)dx 
$$
is a function of $t$.
The wikipedia page on free and bound variables may help.


where does the “boundness” from the bound variable in a definite integral come from?

Consider the statement "Every Human is Mortal": in symbols $\forall x (H(x) \to M(x))$. The statement is not about some specific value of the variable $x$, exactly because there is the universal quantifier "for ALL" that binds the  varibale $x$.
The case of the integral is similar: the integral says "sum ALL value of $f(x)$ for $x$ in the interval $[a,b]$  to get the result".
The result is a number and not a function of $x$: this is why the $x$ in the integral is not free but bound.
